# FileMaker CurrentTime conversion to 24-hour format

Tags: time, filemaker

In FileMaker Pro, I am trying to append the current date and time to a filename to which I export data. If I use

```
Get (CurrentTime)
```

I get 12-hour time, complete with " PM" or " AM" at the end. Is there built-in functionality to return 24-hour time, instead?

[FileMaker help](http://www.filemaker.com/11help/html/func_ref2.32.23.html) says that the format follows the format of system time, but that is not the case. System time is showing as 17:22, but `CurrentTime` is returning 52218 PM. (Mac OS 10.8.5, FileMaker Pro 12.0v4.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filemaker's internal time storage notation is simply the number of seconds elapsed since midnight of the current day.

I.e. 56659 seconds since midnight = 3:44:19 PM.

When exporting data, you can check off the "Apply current layout's data formatting to exported data" checkbox, so that times *displayed* as 24-hour in FMP layouts are *exported* as such.

But, for other internal use such as the file-naming case you're asking about, you will need to use a custom function to convert the output of Get(currentTime) to 24-hour format.

For example, see the [TimeFormatAs ( theTime ; type12or24 )](http://www.briandunning.com/cf/144) function at Briandunning.com.
(Full code of the custom function is pasted below for protection against dead links in the future, but if the link above still works, use that version as it may be more up-to-date:)

---

```
/*---------------------------------------------------------------
Function Name: TimeFormatAs

Syntax: TimeFormatAs ( theTime; type12or24 )

Author - Jonathan Mickelson, Thought Development Corp.
(www.thought-dev.com)
---------------------------------------------------------------*/
Case ( not IsEmpty ( theTime ) ; 
Let ( 
 [ 
// FIXED VARIABLES
padHoursChar           = "" ;        //   Character to pad the Hours with in a text result, (Ex."0", " ", "")
padAMPMChar         = " " ;      //   Character to pad the AM/PM with in a text result, (Ex."0", " ", "")
suffixAM                  = "AM" ;  //    <------------ CHANGE AM Suffix Here
suffixPM                  = "PM" ;   //    <------------ CHANGE PM Suffix Here

// DYN. VARIABLES
theTime = GetAsTime ( theTime ) ;  
hasSeconds = PatternCount ( GetAsText ( theTime ) ; ":" ) = 2 ; 
secs = Mod ( Seconds ( theTime ) ; 60 ) ; 
mins = Mod ( Minute ( theTime ) ; 60 ) + Div ( Seconds ( theTime ) ; 60 ) ; 
hours = Hour ( theTime ) + Div ( Minute ( theTime ) ; 60 ) ; 


// -------------- BEGIN 24 HOUR TIME CALC ----------------------

result24 = GetAsTime ( theTime ) + 1 - 1 ; 

// -------------- BEGIN 12 HOUR TIME CALC ----------------------

hours = Mod ( Hour ( theTime ) ; 12 ) ; 

tempHours =  Case ( ( hours < 1 ) or ( hours - 12 = 0 ) ; 12 ; hours ) ; 
calc12Hours = 
                     Left ( 
                              padHoursChar & padHoursChar ; 
                              2 - Length ( tempHours ) 
                             ) & 
                             tempHours ; 
calc12Minutes = Left ( "00" ; 2 - Length ( mins ) ) & mins ; 
calc12Seconds = Left ( "00" ; 2 - Length ( secs ) ) & secs ;
calc12Suffix    = Case ( Mod ( Hour ( theTime ) ; 24 ) >= 12 ; suffixPM ; suffixAM ) ; 
result12          = calc12Hours & 
                          ":" & calc12Minutes & 
                          // if original time included a non-zero seconds value, display seconds
                          Case ( hasSeconds and secs > 0 ; ":" & calc12Seconds ) &  
                          padAMPMChar & calc12Suffix 
] ; 

Case ( type12or24 >= "24" ; result24 ; result12 ) // END CASE

) // END LET
) // END CASE
```

Comment: See also: http://help.filemaker.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5746/~/formatting-times-in-a-text-calculation

Comment: Thanks very much. I had seen this script but decided to look for something more direct. In the end, I am simply exporting using the available time format and converting it with an external script. It's less trouble this way.